# accessing a javascript variable in handlebars template

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I am getting a php varible in javascript as

```
window.apiUserId = '<?php echo Yii::$app->user->id ?>';
```

And I have a handlebar template as

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
        {{log apiUserId}}

        {{outlet}}
    </script>
```

But the console displays "undefined"

How to log javascript variables in handlebars ?

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](http://handlebarsjs.com/):

```
var context = {title: "My New Post", body: "This is my first post!"}
var html    = template(context);
```

Therefore:

```
var context = {apiUserId: window.apiUserId};
var html    = template(context);
```

I suppose you might manage to make:

```
var html    = template(window);
```

… work, but splurging that much arbitrary data into the function is a good recipe for unexpected results.